# Distributing requests to Selenium Grid RC's?

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I've got a situation here where I have a central selenium grid hub, and several RC's running on my gogrid account. When I access it to run tests, it basically queues all the incoming test requests and executes them serially on only one of the RC's, instead of spreading them out to use available RC's. The tests come from multiple projects, so I'm not looking to parallelize the tests themselves, just to split the requests that come from multiple projects across the multiple RC's. From everything I've read, it seems like selenium grid should be doing this already, yet I only see one RC used to run every single test. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple RCs registered with the same environment?  Each worker can currently only broadcast one environment and the hub assigns work to workers in a circular queue fashion (first registered gets work first).

Answer (score 0):

http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/configuring-and-tuning.html